# How do I know what scales to look for for asymptotic expansion? E.g. cubic case?

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

How do I know what scales to look for for asymptotic expansion? E.g. cubic case?

How do I check for their validity?

Such as in the example here:

[http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/ae.pdf](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/%7Esimonm/ae.pdf)

where they find that

$x^3-x^2-(1+\epsilon)x+1=0$

has double root at $x=1$ and it suggests them to try an expansion in powers of $\epsilon^{1/2}$.

But one could want to solve e.g.

$x^3-5x^2+4x+\epsilon=0$

Given here:

[http://sycon.rutgers.edu/~speer/528s17/Perturbation-DG.pdf](http://sycon.rutgers.edu/%7Espeer/528s17/Perturbation-DG.pdf)

which has roots $x=0,x=1,x=4$.

Comment: If we have a polynomial in $x$ and $\epsilon$, each root is given by a Puiseux series. We can substitute $x = 1 + A \epsilon^p$ into the equation and find $p$ and $A$ by discarding the lower-order terms.

Comment: @Maxim How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation you have
$$
(x+1)(x-1)^2=ϵx\iff (x-1)^2=\frac{ϵx}{1+x}
$$
Close to $x=1$ this gives approximations for the roots there of
$$
x=1\pm\sqrt{\frac{ϵx}{1+x}}\approx 1\pm\sqrt{\fracϵ2}
$$
For the root close to $-1$ you get similarly
$$
x=-1+\frac{ϵx}{(1-x)^2}\approx -1+\fracϵ4
$$

---

For the second equation goes the same,
$$
x(x-1)(x-4)=-ϵ
$$
gives approximations close to the roots of the undisturbed equation of
$$
-\fracϵ4,~~1+\fracϵ3,~~ 4-\fracϵ{12}
$$

Comment: So they try asymptotic expansion in powers of $\epsilon^{1/2}$ because they see like that that the root approximations seem to begin in those powers?

Comment: Yes, the fixed-point equation $x=1\pm\sqrtϵ\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}$ is then regular for $x\approx 1$ and thus the solution can be represented as a power series in the parameter $\sqrtϵ$.